How do you avoid sorting when writing partitioned data in Spark on Palantir Foundry?
Spark is adding a sort operation on the partition keys into query plans.
This slows down builds, increasing memory usage and causing disk spill.
I am sure this is a new behaviour, though I can't verify since spark details for old builds are no longer available.
The write logic:
df = df.repartition('date')

tgt.write_dataframe(df, partition_cols=['date'])

The logical plan looks like:
InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand foundry://...
+- WriteFiles
   +- Sort [date#337 ASC NULLS FIRST], false
      +- Project ...
         +- CollectMetrics ...
            +- RepartitionByExpression [date#337]
               +- Project ...


These issues look like they may be related, but they should be fixed in Spark 3.4+:

SPARK-37194: Avoid unnecessary sort in FileFormatWriter if it's not dynamic partition
SPARK-41914: Sorting issue with partitioned-writing and planned write optimization disabled

I believe until recently our Foundry instance used Spark 3.2.1, but the runtime version has silently been changed to Spark 3.4 and 3.5 regardless of the target Spark version.
Is this sort somehow necessary?
Is it possible to remove it?

It'd be good to know what "write_dataframe" actually does, maybe there is sorting inside of this method. Additionally, could you verify that spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode is not set to dynamic? Because if you have dynamic partitioning I think it is expected that Sparks sorts before writing, at least according to the first ticket that you linked.

Partition overwrite is not supported. I am not sure how to see the source for write_dataframe, it is a Foundry platform API. It should be possible to bypass it, will see if that changes anything

Using built-in spark functions is also adding a sort operation:
df.write.format('parquet').partitionBy('date').save(tgt.filesystem().hadoop_path + '/spark')
So it seems to be a general Spark issue

Could you verify your Spark Version by running spark.version

The environment has sparkVersion: 3.5.1.6

According to SPARK-44512, partitionBy does not guarantee sorting.
It can sort your data (even after you sorted it explicitly):

Although I understand Apache Spark 3.4.0 changes the behavior like the above, I don't think there is a contract that Apache Spark's partitionBy operation preserves the previous ordering .
So, let me close this issue as Not A Problem.

AFAIK this behaviour is not documented.
To remove the sort from the execution plan, you can set this undocumented configuration value:
spark.sql.optimizer.plannedWrite.enabled=false.
The recommended way to manage configuration in Foundry is setting up Spark profile.
You can also set it directly from a transform using the injected ctx parameter:
@transform(
    tgt=Output(...),
)
def compute(ctx, tgt, ...):
    df = ...

    # Prevent sort with partitioned write
    ctx.spark_session.conf.set('spark.sql.optimizer.plannedWrite.enabled', False)

    tgt.write_dataframe(df, partition_cols=['col1']))

